# How to pitch test automation technology for Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, automated-tests, flutter-layout

Our team is building a new store management app using Flutter.
In order to make our CI process better, I want to start building automated tests for it.
I want to make sure that our core features like adding products, purchasing goods, calculating reports and others work.

I was told that I can do such tests only in Dart. However, I haven't ever worked with it (I've originally built tests in Python) and curious if there any other ways to build test automation for Flutter apps except Dart.

Please advise if you have ideas about it!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about. Flutter apps are written in Dart the same way Django apps are written in Python. So why are you shying away from Dart?

In fact, you make it sound like Dart is another framework when Dart is just another language.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using appium for Flutter App !
Look for `appium-flutter-driver` and `appium-uiautomator2-driver` and how you can integrate them in your automation project !